# Http timeout of request from Android to Jetty Resteasy server

Tags: android, http, tcp, jetty, resteasy

I have 1 Jetty Server(Centos 6.4) deploying Resteasy service(use Jedis-Redis), and my mobile clients connect to the service. There's no problem with IOS + WP clients, but Android client sometime encountered request timeout. We used tcpdump for tracking request from client, and I saw that every time Android client encounter timeout, the TCP handshake didn't occur. Android client sent SYN packets and server didn't response, but I used Apache JMeter without any problem at that time.
I have little knowledge of low level TCP/HTTP, I can not identify the problem till to now. If anyone know/encounter or have any suggestion, please tell me. Your words are diamond.
Thank you very much,
Cong.

Comment: From a Jetty Server point of view, it has no knowledge of the client type during TCP handshake.  (the User-Agent information is well after the handshake).  Are you using SSL perchance?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @JoakimErdfelt, but I use only http protocol. Maybe there's mis-config in Centos that I don't know. My question is too general due to my knowledge :(